# Sending data to PLC over serial port in Raspberry Pi using python

Tags: python, serial-port, debian, raspberry-pi, plc

I am running my LX terminal on my Debian installed Raspberry Pi. I have a PLC connected by USB to my Raspberry Pi. I want to send ASCII using python from my terminal I even installed Python Serial but I dont know how to use it. This is the code I have been trying in python. I know the serial port works since I used Linux based minicom to send dsata to plc and it worked. today with python it isnt working the ay i want it to

user ~$ python

```
>>>import serial
>>>ser =  serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
>>>ser.portstr
'/dev/ttyUSB0'
>>>ser
```

What have I been doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: serial.Serial requires a baud rate.  For my Rpi3, I use - ser=serial.Serial("/dev/TTYUSB0",9600) - then I can use - linein=ser.readline() - I am sure there is a similar writeline method in ser also, but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import serial
ser =  serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 4800)
while 1:
    inp = raw_input("Enter the data to send or enter 'exit' to exit:")
    if inp=='exit':
        break
    else:
        ser.write(inp)
```

This piece of code communicates with ttyUSB0 at baudrate 4800. Make sure you are writing at baudrate which is same as that at which your listener is configured to listen at.

It takes a user input as string and sends it through serial. This happens in a loop till exit is entered by the user.

Also make sure that you are running only one process to read from serial on the listening end, or only one of them will read from the serial or both of them will read parts of it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The baud rate of my PLC is fixed at 57600. I get this error :   


  >>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',57600)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in __init__
        self.open()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in open
        raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
    serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

Comment: /dev/ is my system's name.

instead of /dev/ttyUSB0 you should use your device's path.

Comment: Upvote.  For the port, use-> ls /dev/ttyUSB* <- to find it. Then if the PLC is fixed at 57600 this same code should work with the 4800 changed to 57600. Test it out with Minicom to be sure -> apt-get install minicom <- then -> minicom -b 57600 -o -D /dev/ttyUSB0 <-  Ctrl-A q exits, by the way.